# What is Application icon size (83.5x83.5) for iOS?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

In my Delphi Rio iOS project, when I go to `Project options > Icons > Ipad` I can see `Application icon (83.5x83.5)` but what does it mean `83.5x83.5`? It's not possible to make an image of 83.5x83.5 pixels, so what is the desired pixel size?

When I look the dimension of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\Artwork\iOS\iPad\FM_ApplicationIcon_83.5x83.5.png`

It is `83 x 83 pixels`, not `83.5 x 83.5`

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

That is supposed to be iPad Pro icon for @1 scale. But iPad Pro does not have @1 scale, only @2 so this icon size is redundant in Delphi configuration - you can use 83 pixel size to keep Delphi side happy.

Real icon size for iPad Pro will be 83.5 * 2 = 167 pixels - and that size is supported by Delphi.

Comment: @thanks Dalija, this what I was thinking. It's just was hard to believe that the engineer who adds this option in Delphi didn't realize that an icon of 83.5 is not possible and that there is no reason for such icon size!

Comment: @Loki: Better to complain about the Apple engineer who decided that a 2x scale should be 167 pixels (which results in 83.5 @1x) instead of 166 or 168 (which would result in 83 or 84).

Comment: @KenWhite I do not complain :) but I just notice that an option to add an image of 83.5 pixels is just a "nonsense" even if on the "paper" it's must be like this... I have many other things much more serious to complain with Apple engineer ;)